# When is Ghostwriting is legal and ethical?

Tags: academic-writing, research

When is Ghostwriting is legal and ethical?

I used something like a ghostwriter to help quickly publish a research paper. I was called before the chair of my department years ago and called a cheat and a liar. The ghost did appear as lesser co-author as I always intended and had previously agreed. I wanted to explain why it was very ethical given the existence of:

[Legality of academic Ghostwriting](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/4527/legality-of-academic-ghostwriting).

Comment: 2) As-is, answers to the linked question certainly do address ethics. And indeed, on this topic it's hard to discuss one without mentioning the other. I think this question is effectively a duplicate of that one. If you feel this is unclear, I'd rather edit the other question to encompass ethics as well, then have one question for "legality" and a second one for "legality and ethics."

Comment: "Protected" shouldn't keep you from being able to propose an edit. With or without an edit, I think this answer would be appropriate there. So I'll switch this question to duplicate status, and merge the answer into there.